# How can I shorten these value checks?

Tags: c#

I'm making a system to randomly generate stars based on type. The first part is of course telling the system what type of star it is based on rarity. I am having difficulty shortening the actual assigning part based on a random number generator. Here is my current solution.

```
void StarTypeGen () {

    randomGen (x: 0, y: 229000);

    if (Rng <= 228000) {
        StarType++;
        if (Rng <= 36000) {
            StarType++;
            if (Rng <= 22500) {
                StarType++;
                if (Rng <= 9000) {
                    StarType++;
                    if (Rng <= 3750) {
                        StarType++;
                        if (Rng <= 1875) {
                            StarType++;
                            if (Rng <= 10) {
                                StarType++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preload an array with the values and loop through breaking on the first false condition:

```
int[] nums = new int[] { 228000, 36000, 22500, 9000, 3750, 1875, 10 };
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
   if (Rng > nums[i]) break;
   StarType++;
}
```